# different ip address generated when using azure link

Tags: c#, azure, system.net

I have this code on how to get my IP address. Locally the code is running and I got my IP address correctly, but when I run this code using link in azure different ip address is generated.
So for example this is my correct ip address:
"ipaddress": "136.158.26.238",

azure link: https://mysite.cloudapp.azure.com/mywebsvc/mywebsvc.svc/rest/generateip?username=testing3
I got an ip address:
"ipaddress": "13.67.90.14",

Help is highly appreciated.

```
using System.Net;

ipaddress = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/").Replace("\n", "").
```

Comment: Repeat of deleted post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467352/code-getting-ip-address-using-system-net-seems-to-block-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, When you are testing your application in local the `IP ADDRESS` should be shown as per your device/system .
But when you have deployed your application to azure and trying to get `IP Address` as local which is quite not possible . The `IP ADDRESS` should be different from your local.

*The `IP ADDRESS` should  shown in azure when you run the above code for the app service deployed in azure  displays the public IP address.*

For more information [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips).